# Understanding short animation about Dirichlet Process Mixture Model

Tags: clustering, unsupervised-learning, gaussian-mixture-distribution, mixture-distribution, dirichlet-distribution

On the wikipedia page of [Dirichlet Process](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwisvKjAkd_fAhVGEiwKHeGNBgcQFjAAegQICRAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FDirichlet_process&usg=AOvVaw16b6xh_6cZIGbcMj7RGyPF), 
there is the following [video](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=File%3AParameter_estimation_process_infinite_Gaussian_mixture_model.webm).

I don't get the point of the video.

My first impression was that the video was showing the fitting of one-dimensional data using Dirichlet Process Gaussian Distribution, but actually, although the total number of points is fixed to 320, some points every run are being generated while others deleted. 
I don't understand why it's happening and in general what the video is trying to show.

Please, can you explain to me what it's going on?